# oracle collection as function return type

Tags: java, oracle, collections, ibatis

We have a database function to cache sequence values. It accepts a sequence object name and a fetch size, increments the sequence and return the values. 
The return type is a oracle collection.

Here is the definition of the db types used by the function:

```
create or replace type icn_num_type as object(v_inc_num number);
create or replace type icn_num_type_table as table of icn_num_type; --this is returned
```

The values returned by the function are cached on the application side. We are using ibatis for DAO. All this worked well when the function, types and the sequence objects were all in the same schema.

Now we have the function, types and sequences defined in one parent schema. The user schema has synonyms to the all the above mentioned objects. I am facing the following error now:

```
--- The error occurred while executing query procedure.  
--- Check the {? = call seq_inc(?, ?)}.  
--- Check the output parameters (register output parameters failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PICKLER", line 18
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PICKLER", line 58
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

However when we access the function from SQLDeveloper(user schema) it works fine.

Could some one help me on this issue?

Comment: Try prefixing the schema name in the call to "{? = call seq_inc(?, ?)}".

Comment: thanks for your reply Michael. prefixed schema for the function call. ? = call USER_SCHEMA.seq_inc(?, ?) same issue persists.

Comment: are you prefixing the type name too?

Comment: verified this again. when the types and the function are available in the user schema it works fine :(

Comment: Samuel, No I did not prefix schema name explicitly for the types. iBatis does that when it registers the parameters underneath.

Comment: To summarize the issue: Registering output parameters for types that are available to the target schema thru synonyms is failing

Comment: What are the grants ? Does the user schema have a grant on the scalar type and collection type, or just on the function.

Comment: The following grants were given  
Grant execute, debug on userSchema.icn_num_type to userSchema;
Grant execute, debug on userSchema.icn_num_type_table to  userSchema;

Comment: Was not able to fix this issue even with the help of DBAs. We modified the function return type to be a string of CSV :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems there were issues (restrictions / bugs) with synonyms and Object types back in 9iR2 for java. Google for ORA-21700 and DBMS_PICKLER

I suspect you've got some issue with the JDBC driver being used for iBatis that is resolved for the JDBC version used for SQL Developer.

Grab something like SQuirrel SQL Client and try the JDBC driver you are using for iBatis with that to see if you can reproduce.